# Getting value from array object(DateTime)

Tags: php, date

I tried to access the value with $class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d"))[0]['date'] but it seems its impossible to convert the object in array. Is even this form function()[table] a legit method of displaying the data? Seems quite unnatural.

```
function diff_time($lowest,$highest){
   /* input format @$lowest @$highest
                Y-m-d 
   */
   $container = array();
   $dStart = new DateTime($lowest);
   $dEnd  = new DateTime($highest);
   $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
   $containser = array($dStart,$dEnd,$dDiff->days,$dDiff->format('%R'));
   return $containser;
}
var_dump($class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d")));

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-11 00:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-11-05 00:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  [2]=>
  int(267)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "+"
}

print_r($class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d"))[0]);

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-02-11 00:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Comment: What value are you trying to get?

Comment: @JohnConde [0]["date"] and [1]["date] since [2] and [3] are easy to get :)

Comment: I still have no idea what value you want.

Comment: @JohnConde  ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-02-11 00:00:00" and  ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-11-05 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that date is a field of an object, so try

```
$class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d"))[0]->date;
```

Comment: Notice:  Undefined property: DateTime::$date for line $class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d"))[0]->date

Comment: Please, what is the output of `print_r($class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d"))[0]);`?

Comment: Well, it seems really strange to me that you can't get date as I have suggested to you, if you do `$class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d"))[0]-> timezone`, do you get the value?

Comment: Undefined property: DateTime::$timezone NULL return

Comment: Try `$class->diff_time('2014-02-11',date("Y-m-d"))[0]->format('Y-m-d H:i');`. It is likely that those fields are private.